# New post / threads on forums

Tags: php, cookies

I'm currently working on my own basic forum, for my website.

The question is, what is the best way, to check new post / threads on forum for each other user AND guest? I think , cookies are the option in this case.

But I need some ideas on how to do that.

Maybe there are any ready to use PHP classes?

Thank you in advance,

Kind Regards,

Lucas.

Comment: There are ready to use nice blog platforms, you can learn a lot by browsing their code; try MyBB or phpBB, their code is not the most beautiful around, but it'll give you an idea. A forum it's not a trivial job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can encode  the last visit date/time of a particular visitor and store it in a cookie. Now you just have to compare that date with the forum posts dates and format the posts newer than the last visited date in a different manner (e.g. make those posts title bold). Further you may even encode and store which posts have have been viewed by the user and show posts not viewed till now as fresh/current.